# Sequential execution js

Tags: javascript, ajax, sequential

I am developping a project that needs to deal with ajax calls in a sequential manner. The code I have is something like:

```
for(var j=0; j<3;j++) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:url[j],
                    async:false
                }).done(function(result){
                    var data = result.data;
                    for(var i=0; i < data.length;i++){
                        analyses += "<div><div id=\"" + data[i] + "\" class=\"module\">";
                        analyses += "<br/>Analysis : " + data[i] + "<br/>";
                        analyses += "</div></div>";
                        $("#analysesPlaceHolder").html(analyses);
                    }
                });

            }
```

However, now it just randomly selects the url from the list (sometimes it is the first, sometimes it is not). How can a make the execution sequential so that the code first performs the first ajax call, then the second etc.

Comment: Your `$.ajax` call is sync since you specify `async:false` and also you're taking the url from an `array` which you're looping in order... probably the `randomly` problem is in the part where you create the `url` array.

Comment: Probably `$.when` is what you want...take a look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend using ajax calls within a loop.

Here is a better way, which increments the count in the ajax callback, then fires the next ajax request:

```
var urlCount = 0;

var makeAjaxCall = function(count) {
    $.ajax({
        url:url[count],
    }).done(function(result){
        var data = result.data;
        for(var i=0; i < data.length;i++){
            analyses += "<div><div id=\"" + data[i] + "\" class=\"module\">";
            analyses += "<br/>Analysis : " + data[i] + "<br/>";
            analyses += "</div></div>";
            $("#analysesPlaceHolder").html(analyses);
        }

        urlCount++;
        if (urlCount < 3) {
            makeAjaxCall(urlCount);
        }
    });
}

makeAjaxCall(urlCount);
```

You could also chain ajax calls using promises, as stated in the comment above.